# Al crear un gráfico en reportviewer, me sale un error en el documento pdf generado

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

Resulta que estaba probando como hacer un grafico con reportviewer, pero cuando se crea el documento pdf, en la parte donde debería estar elgrafico, dice el siguiente error:

> no se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.reportviewer.DataVisualization,version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

Yo tengo **Microsoft.ReportViewer.2015.Runtime version 12.0.2.2402**, descargado e instalado desde Nugets Packages.

En referencias tengo las siguientes dlls de reportviewer:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
```

y desde el código hago llamada de esta forma:

```
 private FileResult GenerarInformeLibroVenta(string format)
    {
        String sql = "select familia,categoria,ponderado from productos";
        conexion.conectar();
        MySqlDataAdapter datos = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion.con);
        conexion.cerrar();
        DataTable dt_lventfinal = new DataTable();
        datos.Fill(dt_lventfinal);

        Reportes reportes = new Reportes();
        string nombreDataSource = "DataSet_Existencias";
        string nameArchivoExcel = "Report_libroVentasMensual";
        string nombreReporte = "Graficos.rdlc";
        int size_parametro = 1;
        ReportParameter[] Parametros = new ReportParameter[size_parametro];
        Parametros[0] = new ReportParameter("empresa", "nombre Empresa");
        return reportes.GetFileContentResultParametro(Parametros, nombreReporte, dt_lventfinal, nombreDataSource, format, null, nameArchivoExcel);
    }
```

La clase en donde encuentra:

```
 public FileContentResult GetFileContentResultParametro(ReportParameter[] parametro, string nombreReporte, dynamic query, string nombreDataSource, String format, String deviceInfo, String fileDownloadName)
    {
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/" + nombreReporte);

        report.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Value = query;
        reportDataSource.Name = nombreDataSource;
        report.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        report.SetParameters(parametro);
        report.Refresh();
        String mimeType;
        String encoding;
        String filenameExtension;
        String[] streamIds;
        Warning[] warnings;
        FileContentResult fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(report.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings), mimeType);
        fileContentResult.FileDownloadName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileDownloadName, filenameExtension);

        return fileContentResult;
    }
```

Me gustaria saber como solucionar el problema, quizas me falta agregar alguna dll, o agregar algun atributo en el codigo C#. Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Así se me ve la ruta donde esperaba que ir a buscar a buscar la dll.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero desde consola, para buscar la ubicación de la dll, me aparece en esta ubicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero intenta instalar el paquete redistribuible de ReportViewer 2015 en tu computador de desarrollo. Con esto aseguras que todas las dlls están correctamente instaladas.
El paquete lo puedes descargar de este link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

Tambien puedes copiar la dll desde la siguiente ubicación de tu disco `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization\<Version de ReportViewer>` hacia tu carpeta `bin` para asegurar que la aplicación siempre encuentre ese archivo.

Comment: en mi caso tengo windows 7, y la unica ruta que pillo es esta:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.resources
dentro de ella hay varias carpetas que contiene dlls, por ejemplo alguna de ellas son v4.0_12.0.0.0_de_89845dcd8080cc91 v4.0_12.0.0.0_es_89845dcd8080cc91 v4.0_12.0.0.0_fr_89845dcd8080cc91

Comment: Además, la dll que estan se llama Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.resources.dll

Edite mi pregunta, puse una foto de lo que tengo con la ruta assembly, hasta ahí llego

Comment: Ya lo solucione, tuve que referenciarlo desde el mismo visual studio la ruta que me indicas

Comment: Que bien! Me alegra que hayas solucionado tu inconveniente.